Mapreduce doesn't successfully do INSERT / CREATE TABLE from existing table operations
I created 2 tables and in beeline (hive) and it worked quickly.
However, I am not able to create a new table from those two. Mapreduce is taking forever.
Also,
The url to track the job: http://anushkahp14:8088/proxy/application_1716189650320_0005/  returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
# Movies table
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE movies (
  movieId INT,
  title STRING,
  genres STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatorChar" = ",",
  "quoteChar" = "\"",
  "escapeChar" = "\\"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/movielens/movies'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

# Ratings table
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ratings (
  userId INT,
  movieId INT,
  rating DOUBLE,
  rating_timestamp BIGINT
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatorChar" = ",",
  "quoteChar" = "\"",
  "escapeChar" = "\\"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/movielens/ratings'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

I am attempting:
CREATE TABLE avg_movie_ratings AS
SELECT movieId, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM ratings
GROUP BY movieId;

which starts a map-reduce job, which is struck.
I have the hadoop and hive running.
However,
The url to track the job: http://anushkahp14:8088/proxy/application_1716189650320_0005/  returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Terminal output
Please help.
