YARN cluster is not recognizing any active NodeManagers (Total Nodes: 0)
I am trying to run an application on using hive and hadoop.
And, my YARN cluster is not recognizing any active NodeManagers
Terminal output on: yarn node -list
anushkakundu@AnushkaHP14:/opt/hadoop/bin$ /opt/hadoop/bin/yarn node -list
2024-05-23 17:07:47,933 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
Total Nodes:0
         Node-Id         Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers

One more thing:
My terminal reads:
 The url to track the job: http://AnushkaHP14:8088/proxy/application_1716465092573_0001/

However http://AnushkaHP14:8088/proxy/application_1716465092573_0001/ says This site can’t be reached
I have done the folowing:

Started hadoop (verified by running jps), started hive (metastore and hiveserver2 are active.)
Modified my yarn-site.xml to allocate appropiate resources.
Restared everything.

Any suggestions are really welcome.

Does jps show a nodemanager? Did you look at the logs of any nodemanager for errors or connection issues? What exact changes to the Yarn-site.xml were done? Is this any different from your last question that you could've edited? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78506666/mapreduce-doesnt-successfully-do-insert-create-table-from-existing-table-oper

If http://AnushkaHP14:8088 is your local machine then you can try http://localhost:8088  otherwise, you'll need to change the reported ip/hostname of the nodemanager in yarn-site.xml

@OneCricketeer yes nodemanager is running,
anushkakundu@AnushkaHP14:/opt/hadoop/bin$ jps
9761 Jps
5253 NodeManager
4520 NameNode
4904 SecondaryNameNode
5112 ResourceManager
4668 DataNode

@OneCricketeer, upon your asking i looked for errors.
I guess I get the crux of the problem now. I will reconfigure the space allotted. ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService: Most of the disks failed. 1/1 local-dirs usable space is below configured utilization percentage
Thank you :)

Yes, I understand I could have edited my previous question. But I identified that YARN cluster is not recognizing any active NodeManagers, which i didn't back then. I understand, will keep in mind next time.
